# Joining 3 tables returning mixed results (mysql)

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables:

EMPLEADOS
ALTAS
BAJAS

This is some example data:

EMPLEADOS

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+
| id_empleado | nombres    | ap_paterno  |
+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 1020        | JUAN       | FUENTES     |
+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 1021        | JOSE       | FLORES      |
+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

ALTAS

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| id_alta     | id_empleado  | fecha_alta  | tipo      |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 958         | 1020         | 2015-02-27  | ALTA      |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 961         | 1020         | 2015-02-26  | REINGRESO |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 972         | 1020         | 2015-03-19  | REINGRESO |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| 1003        | 1020         | 2015-05-19  | REINGRESO |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

BAJAS

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| id_baja     | id_empleado  | id_motivo   | fecha_baja   |finiquitado |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| 896         | 1020         | 1           | 2015-03-12   | 0          |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
| 909         | 1020         | 1           | 2015-03-30   | 1          |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

I’m using the Following Query:

```
SELECT 
    EMPLEADOS.id_empleado, ALTAS.id_alta, 
    ALTAS.fecha_alta, ALTAS.tipo, 
    BAJAS.id_baja, BAJAS.fecha_baja 
    FROM EMPLEADOS 
    LEFT JOIN ALTAS ON EMPLEADOS.id_empleado = ALTAS.id_empleado
    LEFT JOIN BAJAS ON EMPLEADOS.id_empleado = BAJAS.id_empleado
WHERE EMPLEADOS.id_empleado = 1020
GROUP BY ALTAS.fecha_alta, BAJAS.fecha_baja
ORDER BY fecha_alta DESC, fecha_baja DESC
```

And I’m getting this result:

```
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| id_empleado | id_alta | fecha_alta | tipo     | id_baja | fecha_baja |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 1020        | 1003    | 2015-05-19 | REINGRESO| 909     | 2015-03-30 |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 1020        | 1003    | 2015-05-19 | REINGRESO| 896     | 2015-03-12 |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 1020        | 972     | 2015-03-19 | REINGRESO| 909     | 2015-03-30 |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 1020        | 972     | 2015-03-19 | REINGRESO| 895     | 2015-03-12 |
```

... And so on up to 8 results (mixing all the ALTAS (4) with the BAJAS (2) info of tables)

When the desired result is:

```
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| id_empleado | id_alta | fecha_alta | tipo     | id_baja | fecha_baja |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 1020        | 1003    | 2015-05-19 | REINGRESO|         |            |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 1020        |         |            |          | 909     | 2015-03-30 |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 1020        | 972     | 2015-03-19 | REINGRESO|         |            |
```

...And so on up to 6 results (4 ALTAS data and 2 BAJAS data)

Why is my query wrong?

Comment: the joins are doing exactly what they should be. taking 2+ separate tables and "combining" them (aka literally joining them) into a single table. all records from `empleados` and any matching records from the other two tables, joined 1:n. you probably want an `outer` join instead of a `left`

Comment: When I use OUTER instead of LEFT Join, I can't get any result (blank)...

Comment: Why aren't `id_alta = 961` and `id_alta = 958` in the desired result?

Comment: And why isn't `id_baja = 896` in the result?

Comment: the examples were incomplete and ordered DESC by fecha_alta and fecha_baja, but they were in the complete results

Comment: Bamar, why you deleted your answer? it was correct!!!

Comment: @benjamingranados Please use `@` before usernames, so the user will be notified that you sent them a message. It also does auto-complete, so it spells my name correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do separate joins with each table, and then combine them with `UNION`. Use `NULL` as a placeholder for the columns from the other table.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT e.id_empleado, a.id_alta, a.fecha_alta, NULL AS id_baja, NULL AS fecha_baja
    FROM EMPLEADOS AS e
    LEFT JOIN ALTAS AS a ON e.id_empleado = a.id_empleado
    WHERE e.id_empleado = 1020
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.id_empleado, NULL, NULL, b.id_baja, b.fecha_baja
    FROM EMPLEADOS AS e
    LEFT JOIN BAJAS AS b ON e.id_empleado = b.id_empleado
    WHERE e.id_empleado = 1020
) AS u
ORDER BY fecha_alta DESC, fecha_baja DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf455/11)

Answer (score 0):

suggestion:
you will need to run it with each table separately and use union to append data.
Keep the columns values (of columns from bajas) as Null while joining Altas and vice versa..